# AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword throws System.AggregateException and MsalServiceException

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, jwt, token, bearer-token

AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword throws System.AggregateException and MsalServiceException:

1st Exception:

> System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Federated
> service at
> [https://autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com/domain.com/winauth/trust/2005/usernamemixed?client-request-id=[ID]](https://autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com/domain.com/winauth/trust/2005/usernamemixed?client-request-id=%5BID%5D)
> returned error: Authentication Failure )'

2nd Exception:

> MsalServiceException: Federated service at
> [https://autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com/domain.com/winauth/trust/2005/usernamemixed?client-request-id=[ID]](https://autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com/domain.com/winauth/trust/2005/usernamemixed?client-request-id=%5BID%5D)
> returned error: Authentication Failure

```
string clientId = "client-id";
string tenant = "tenant-id";
    
// Open connection
string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant;
string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
IPublicClientApplication app;
app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                          .WithAuthority(authority)
                          .Build();
var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in user.Password.ToCharArray())  // you should fetch the password
securePassword.AppendChar(c);  // keystroke by keystroke
var results = app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, user.UserName, securePassword).ExecuteAsync().Result.IdToken;
```

Comment: Have you checked your password? Is it correct?

Comment: Could you please check if you have enabled `Allow public client flows``?

Comment: @JimXu Allow public client flows is enabled

Comment: @Tassisto Have you enabled mfa for your user account?

Comment: @JimXu where can I enable this?

Comment: please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/tutorial-enable-azure-mfa

Comment: I get this Message --> AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: 'api://guid'.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you configure redirect URL?

Comment: Under Azure Active Directory > App Registrations > My App > Authentication  > https:// myapi.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc

Comment: Could you please tell me which type of application you use?

Comment: I thought I had the solution but I was accessing the API with an ID token, which isn't a best practice. I have to access API's with the Access Token. I check the validity of the Access token on jwt.io, it is valid when decoding with algorithm RS256.

Answer (score 0):

Your `scope` is set incorrectly. I think you want to call your custom api instead of ms graph api, so you should get a token for your expose api. The `scope` you set in the code is the permissions of ms graph api instead of your custom api scope.

Therefore, you need to set the `scope` to: `api://{api app client id}/.default`.

Comment: what is .default for ?

Comment: @Tassisto The `/.default` scope is a way to silently request. see the explanation of the official doc:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#the-default-scope

Comment: It says: "Then the code returns an id_token, rather than an access token."
Isn't it required to access an API with an access token instead of an id token?

Comment: @Tassisto  Of course, you must use an access token.